# Donetnuke (DNN) importing template error

Tags: templates, dotnetnuke

When i try to import the project template i got the error
Why it was happening, and how to solve it?
I export the template by checking Content and Files option

Please help someone who have encountered this before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a project template, it is a Portal or Site template (possibly a page template), but not a Project.

That sure looks like the error is telling you that the TAB (page) already exists. Check the XML file that the template created to see if you have multiple TABS in there with the same name/path.

Are you perhaps creating a TAB with the same name as the "ALIAS"

Example, in the Parent site you have http://site/CHILDNAME and you are now trying to create a portal called http://site/CHILDNAME?